# Integral $\int \frac{dx}{\left(1+x^{2014}\right)\left(1+x^{\alpha}\right)},\quad \alpha\neq 0.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

How to solve indefinite integral:
$$\int \frac{dx}{\left(1+x^{2014}\right)\left(1+x^{\alpha}\right)},\quad \alpha\neq 0.$$

Comment: The technique you can use is called partial fraction decomposition

Comment: Are you sure that the power is $2014$? Isn't it $1024$? Even it is $1024$, what about $\alpha$? Is it real, integer or natural? Anyway, I think your integral has not a closed form. Maybe Taylor series works.

Comment: Is this a question from a contest?  If so, then provide more information about the contest and add the [tag:contest-math] tag.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (works if $\alpha$ is a natural number) :

Try a similarly looking integral

$$\int\frac{1}{(1+x^8)(1+x^5)} dx$$

Note: the integral can also be done if $\alpha$ is rational, altough the formula changes its form.

Comment: I would say “rational” rather than natural.

Comment: @Lucian: You are right, the integral can be resolved if $\alpha$ is rational, but the formula changes its form. I restated the answer.